# Ignore specific exit code in zsh and bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I am looking for a way to ignore a specific exit code that works across zsh and bash.

In my example I want to ignore the exit code `134`.
I have managed to come up with a working example for bash:

```sh
node fail.js || STATUS=$? && (if [ $STATUS == 134 ]; then true; else exit $STATUS; fi)
```

Any improvements on that are appreciated as well, but my struggle begins with zsh.
This command won’t work in zsh. I have found out, that `||` is used in zsh to split commands, but I haven’t found an equivalent for the way I want it to work.

Comment: This doesn't apply so much in zsh (which doesn't try to conform with POSIX standards), but note that in the POSIX world, all-caps names are reserved for variables meaningful to standard-defined tools, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have unintended side effects on POSIX-compliant tools.

Comment: (and as rowboat says, `==` is nonstandard; the POSIX-compliant string comparison operator in `[` is just a single `=` -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
your_command || (exit "$(($? == 134 ? 0 : $?))")
```

This uses `exit` in a subshell to change an exit status of 134 to 0,  or else pass through the value if `your_command` fails.

`$(( expr ))` is for shell arithmetic expansion. Within this context, operators such as binary `==` and the conditional `?:` ternary are standard.

I don't think that `||` would be an issue in zsh. Perhaps using the non-standard `==` operator with `[` instead of `[[`. Zsh tries to conform to the POSIX standard when using `[` or `test`.

`man zshbuiltins` says of `test`/`[`:

> The command attempts to implement POSIX and its extensions where these are specified. Unfortunately there are intrinsic ambiguities in the syntax; in particular there is no distinction between test operators and strings that resemble them. The standard attempts to resolve these for small numbers of arguments (up to four); for five or more arguments compatibility cannot be relied on. Users are urged wherever possible to use the `[[` test syntax which does not have these ambiguities.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wants to exit in the success case.

Comment: The other concern is compatibility with scripts using `set -e` -- using `||` marks the left-hand side as "checked" and stops the shell from exiting before even reaching the statement inspecting `$?`, as it would with a newline or `;` acting as command separator were `set -e` enabled.

Comment: ...and if you want the `exit` to exit the parent shell interpreter, rather than a transient subshell, consider `{ ...; }` (a grouping operator that provides to commands to run in the parent shell's context) instead of `(...)` (which creates a new context, such that `exit` only exits that context rather than the larger script)

Comment: I like how short this command is and that it does not create a temporary variable. But it’s harder to wrap my head around it. Could you elaborate on what is going on? Why does `==` work here and why do you need the double set of paranthesis in the subshell? Sorry, I am not that familiar with scripting …

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is for the script to keep running should the node interpreter not fail, this might look like:

```
node fail.js || { rc=$?; if [[ $rc != 134 ]]; then exit "$rc"; fi; }
```

Comment: Ah thank you, my main problem seemed to be the `==`. I would keep the round brackets, because I do not want the parent shell to exit, I just want the proper exit code of that one-liner. For me this is more readable, than @rowboat’s solution, but I like that in that solution you do not need an temporary variable.

Comment: Interesting. I would expect `==` to cause incompatibility with some common versions of sh, but it's actually a surprise to me that zsh doesn't implement the same nonstandard extension that bash does.